# Pass Data From Activity To Dialog

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to pass data from an activity onto a dialog box. I am trying to call `showDialog(int);`, however i don't see a way to pass any data to the dialog box.
I need to pass a string to the dialog box in order to display a confirmation :)

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are targeting Android 2.2 (API Level 8 or higher) you can use

```
 public final boolean showDialog (int id, Bundle args)
```

And pass your arguments in `Bundle`. See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog%29).

If you want to support older Android versions, you should save your arguments in `Activity` class members and then access them from your [`onPrepareDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29) function. Note that [`onCreateDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29) won't fit your needs as it's called only once for dialog creation.

```
class MyActivity {

    private static int MY_DLG = 1;
    private String m_dlgMsg;

    private showMyDialog(String msg){
        m_dlgMsg = msg;
        showDialog(MY_DLG);
    }

    private doSomething() {
        ...
        showMyDlg("some text");
    }

    protected void onCreateDialog(int id){
        if(id == MY_DLG){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
            ....
            return builder.create();
         }
         return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }        

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog (int id, Dialog dialog){ 
         if(id == MY_DLG){ 
            AlertDialog adlg = (AlertDialog)dialog;
            adlg.setMessage(m_dlgMsg);
         } else {
            super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
         }             
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, sounds good :) The only problem is that where you have doSomething(), I am calling showDialog from within an inline onClick event, so it doesn't seem to be passing the values through, i'm not sure why...

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but you can use the `setArguments` method if you are using a custom dialog.

```
String myString = "How to do it"
DialogFragment newFragment = new AddUserDialog();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("number", myString); //The first parameter is the key that will be used to retrieve the value, which is the second parameter.
                newFragment.setArguments(args);
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "add_a_member");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing showDialog(int) the Activity's [onCreateDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29) method is called. There you must create a dialog instance and return it, and it will be shown.

Then you are creating a dialog, you have a full access to your class' fields and can use values of them to adjust parameters and content of created dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
//`enter code here`I used shared preferences and it worked.
**in your activity:**

//your field:  public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = null;

                        String template = selectedItem.getProduct().getName();
            String num = selectedItem.getNumber();
            String id = selectedItem.getId();
            String location = selectedItem.getLocationName();


        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
            prefEditor.putString("template", template);
            prefEditor.putString("num", num);
            prefEditor.putString("id", id);
            prefEditor.putString("location", location);
            prefEditor.commit();

**in your dialog class:**
//In my case I needed to add activity because how i created dialog:

public MyDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        this.context = context;
        final Activity activity = (Activity) context;

              // If you dont call activity you can try context.getpreferences(......)
        SharedPreferences prefs = ((Activity) context)
                .getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String template = prefs.getString("template", "");
        String num = prefs.getString("num", "");
        String id = prefs.getString("id", "");
        String location = prefs.getString("location", "");

}`enter code here`
```